# Can I see/retrieve global statistics using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to retrieve global stats from Google Analytics. If not directly via an API, then doing HTTP requests and RegEx. However, I can't seem to find any place to gather such data. Where are the global stats? Obviously we talk about anonymous statistics that should not be against Google's policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they will be providing a comparison newsletter for those that "opt in" to anonymous stats. http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/03/evolution-of-analytics-benchmarking.html

Answer (score 2):

Try [statcounter's global stats](http://gs.statcounter.com/)

Comment: There is a downloadable CSV version of the graph that could serve as an API for repeated querying.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the docs?

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/

Comment: Wait, you want stats for a site you own or the entire internet?

Comment: The entire Internet. I am seeking for global anonymous statistics of Google Analytics.

Comment: I don't think that's on the cards buddy. Sorry